# Jsoup returning empty elements

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing this page: http://www.catedralaltapatagonia.com/invierno/partediario.php

This is the page source code

```
 <!-- COMIENZO PESTAÑA METEOROLOGIA -->
<div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
<div class="contenedor">
  <div id="pd_foto_fondo">
<br />
<div id="meteo_contenedor_avalanchas">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ULTIMA ACTUALIZACION PARTE DIARIO:     FECHA: 03 de Junio de 2015  HORA: 09:00 hs</div>
  <br />......
```

and this is the code i use to get the data

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements div = document.select("div#meteo_contenedor_avalanchas");
 TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
        textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(div));
```

But I receive an empty result.

I need ths text: ULTIMA ACTUALIZACION PARTE DIARIO:     FECHA: 03 de Junio de 2015  HORA: 09:00 hs

how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In place of

`Elements div = document.select("div#meteo_contenedor_avalanchas");`

Add below code,

```
String div = document.getElementById("meteo_contenedor_avalanchas").toString();
```

Comment: Not work.....NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.jsoup.nodes.Element org.jsoup.nodes.Element.child(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: again....NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.toString()' on a null object reference